# Git remote pull using GitHub deployment keys - Permission Denied

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I have done the following steps to setup ssh deployment keys with our git repo for it to be able to git pull without a username and password:

Note: I am on AWS EC2 / Ubuntu 14.04.3

1. Run `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "ownersEmail@gmail.com"` these are then saved as id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in ~/.ssh/
2. The deployment public key (id_rsa.pub) is added on the GitHub online UI in the deployment keys section
3. The directory is already cloned in /var/www/ directory, this is working all good via HTTPS for pulling
4. Try `sudo git pull git@github.com:ownersUsername/OurRepo.git` and get the following error

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Another Note: This repository is private under another users account.

Also, when I try `ssh git@github.com` I get:

> Hi userName/Repo! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
>   Connection to github.com closed.

And the deployment key comes up as being used. Have been on this issue for greater than 4 hours now and any would would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you're using sudo, which runs the command as root, and it will try to use the root's keys not your user's keys.

What you want to do is:

1. give your user/group write access to `/var/www`
2. run the pull/clone as the user, not the root user.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a git pull you don't need the link.

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

You need the full url for the **clone** command

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:ownersUsername/OurRepo.git
```

To test if your ssh key is good use this:

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

Comment: Hey, I still seem to be getting the error even when trying to clone:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Are you behind proxy? Also check your .gitconfig file to verify that you do not have any protocol configuration (htp/https/git)